# Filter result drop down menu not working with Rails Bootstrap Forms GEM

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing this to improve my RoR skills. I am trying to style a form that I have created. This is my original code for the form.

```
<%= form_tag('/quotation/tints/generate') do %>
    <%= label :manufacturer_id, 'Manufacturer' %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= collection_select(:tint, :manufacturer_id, Manufacturer.order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Manufacturer" }) %> 
    </div>

    Model:
    <div class="field">
        <%= grouped_collection_select(:tint, :model_id, Manufacturer.order(:name), :models, :name, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Model"}) %> 
    </div>

    <%= label :price_front, 'Front Tint' %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= collection_select(:price, :price_front, Price.where('catogery_id' => "1").order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Front Tint"}) %> 
    </div>

    <%= label :price_rear, 'Size and Back Tint' %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= collection_select(:price, :price_rear, Price.where('catogery_id' => "1").order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Side & Rear Tint"}) %> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= submit_tag 'Submit', class: "button btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

User has to select `Manufacturer` first in order to select the `Model`. The `Model` will be filtered based on the `Manufacturer`. This is the script that I use to active the action. It works perfectly.

```
jQuery ->
    $('#tint_model_id').parent().hide()
    models = $('#tint_model_id').html()
    $('#tint_manufacturer_id').change ->
        manufacturer = $('#tint_manufacturer_id :selected').text()
        options = $(models).filter("optgroup[label='#{manufacturer}']").html()
        if options
            $('#tint_model_id').html(options)
            $('#tint_model_id').parent().show()
        else
            $('#tint_model_id').empty()
            $('#tint_model_id').parent().hide()
```

Now, I am trying to style the form and dropdown menu. I am using `bootstrap_form` gem to make my life easier. In order to use the gem, I have to change the form to work with the gem, I changed my code of the form to the code below.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag url: '/quotation/tints/generate' do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.collection_select :manufacturer_id, Manufacturer.order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Manufacturer"} %> 
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.grouped_collection_select :model_id, Manufacturer.order(:name), :models, :name, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Model"} %> 
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.collection_select :price_front, Price.where('catogery_id' => "1").order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Front Tint"} %> 
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.collection_select :price_rear, Price.where('catogery_id' => "1").order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Side & Rear Tint"} %> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= submit_tag 'Submit', class: "button btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The form looks beautifully and working as in generating a view after it is submitted. However, I found out that the filter option no longer works. User is able to select `Model` before selecting the `Manufacturer`. I did try to `bundle install` and restart my rails server to try to get it work.

My question is does `bootstrap_form` gem works with the script that filter the model based on the manufacturer? Is there any other way that I can implant my script to work with bootstrap css?

More info:
This is what I have for `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

I have added a picture below to illustrate what I mean.
[image: Before and After]

Comment: Is the id `#tint_model_id` present after you applied bootstrap to your form? Can you confirm it by looking at html tags generated?

Comment: Nope, it is changed to `_model_id` from `tint_model_id`

Comment: Because the id is changed your jquery doesn't work anymore. Keep the collections as it was before, remove `f.`, as you are using a form_tag it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks for pointing it out! I can't remove the `f.` as it is required when I use the GEM. I have posted a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Bootstrap changed the ID when I use `bootstrap_form` GEM. Correct script shown below.

```
jQuery ->
    $('#_model_id').parent().hide()
    models = $('#_model_id').html()
    $('#_manufacturer_id').change ->
        manufacturer = $('#_manufacturer_id :selected').text()
        options = $(models).filter("optgroup[label='#{manufacturer}']").html()
        if options
            $('#_model_id').html(options)
            $('#_model_id').parent().show()
        else
            $('#_model_id').empty()
            $('#_model_id').parent().hide()
```